# Array inside of array in HTML to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

Is it possible to create a structure like this on HTML ?

Companies-> (employee,
             payment,
            etc....);
            (employee,
             payment,
            etc....)

I know that I can create arrays in HTML to use them in PHP through POST... but is it possible to create an array inside of an array ?

And is it correct or there is a better way os of doing that ?

I am guessing that it would be something like this...:

```
<input name="Companies[employee[]]"/>
<input name="Companies[payment[]]"/>
```

PS: I can't use 2 diffent IDs or names because it's the User who decides how many entries the form will have.

Comment: You would save yourself a lot of trouble if you'd just limit the form to the entry of 1 person at a time. If you must add multiple people, create something like an CSV reader and have people enter their data in a spreadsheet. You could even create a Google Documents spreadsheet as input for your web application. (Ab)using forms to enter massive amounts of data is never a great user experience.

Comment: You can always make a complex form and then jsonize it and sent it to php then :)

Comment: <input name="Companies[employee][]"/>
<input name="Companies[payment][]"/>

Comment: Yeah. Sometime if companies are more then he cann't go with company1 , company2 ..... etc like that right. It should be an array..

Comment: @HenryvanMegen great tip I will use it in another view. Unfortunately at this one I've been forced to use the array inside of an array by the bussiness rules... And I also recommend the others to follow your answer!

Comment: @Suresh Perfect worked like a charm in here, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code as below.

```
<input name="Companies[employee][]"/>
<input name="Companies[payment][]"/>
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer as it will helpful for others as well.